# Javascript: How to Reselect a Selector And Rerun the Function to Give a New Result

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am new to Javascript - apologies of this is a dumb question:

I have a order form, with product | quantity | price laid out in a row.

"product" is a select drop down

There are as many as 35 such rows on a single form. The code I have arrived at works great, *untill you go back* on yourself and want to change an earlier "quantity" or change the "product" from the drop down.

**Problem**

1)Changing the product: My code does not recognise that a different product has been selected. The product_id does not get updated. Therefore the price being held in the global var is wrong and the cost comes out wrong.

2) Changing the quantity: The code does recognise that the quantity has changed, however, it still multiplies the price being held in the global price

**Solution**: If I change the quantity, or if I change the product in the select drop down ( ie the product_id) then my code need to rerun and get the new price. I need to be able to clear the global price variable and set a new price for multiplication. If it's the same product, then the price will be the same - no matter.

This is what I have got so far:

```
var price = 0;

// first we grab the product id //
$(".product_id").on('change', function() {
  var value = parseFloat($(this).val()); // product_id
  console.log('prod_id', value);

  // then we use the product_id to grab the price using AJAX //
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'product_prices/' + value,
    success: function(data) {
      var data = JSON.parse(data);
      var result = data[0].price;
      price = Number(result).toFixed(2); // price
      console.log('price', price)

    }
  });
});


// We take the price and multiply by quantity to calculate the cost
$(".quantity").on('change', function() {


  var quantity = parseInt($(this).val());
  var num = (price * quantity);
  var cost = num.toFixed(2);

  $(this).parents(':eq(1)').find('input').filter(".cost").val(cost)
  console.log('cost', cost);
});
```

Comment: Your `price` variable is the price of whatever product the user selected last, which may be on a different row from the quantity he's changing. You need to save the price for each row, not a single global variable.

Comment: Have you tried `var value = parseFloat($(this option:selected).text());`

Comment: @Barmar Understood - however, I would not need to save each row price, if I could grab the new product_id and rerun the ajax call giving the new price. Any suggestions hows I might achieve this ? Thanks.

Comment: When the user changes a quantity, use DOM traversal functions like `$(this).closest('tr').find('.product_id')` to find the product on the same row. Then make the AJAX call with that value to get the price.

Comment: But doing an AJAX call every time the user changes the quantity seems excessive. Why not just save the price in the DOM when you do the product AJAX call? E.g. `$(this).closest('tr').data('price', data[0].price)`.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks ! as I said, I am very new to JS .. still learning. I did not realise I could do that. I am not clear where to incorporate this array into my code so that the price of every row is saved.

Can you help ? thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a global `price` variable, use jQuery's [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) method to save each row's price in the DOM.

```
$(".product_id").on('change', function() {
  var value = parseFloat($(this).val()); // product_id
  console.log('prod_id', value);
  var row = $(this).closest("tr");
  // then we use the product_id to grab the price using AJAX //
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'product_prices/' + value,
    success: function(data) {
      var data = JSON.parse(data);
      var result = data[0].price;
      var price = Number(result).toFixed(2); // price
      console.log('price', price);
      row.data('price', price); // remember the row's current price
    }
  });
});


// We take the price and multiply by quantity to calculate the cost
$(".quantity").on('change', function() {
  var row = $(this).closest('tr');
  var price = row.data('price');
  if (price) {
      var quantity = parseInt($(this).val());
      var num = (price * quantity);
      var cost = num.toFixed(2);

      row.find("input.cost").val(cost)
      console.log('cost', cost);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help !